# JetpackCompose, request focus on any of my child

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a LazyList of items, each item has layers of nested children wrapped in other components. For each item, there could be 2 or 3 focusables nested. From the list level, how to I request focus on any focusable child of nth item?

```
val autoFocusIndex = n

LazyList{

   itemsIndex(data){ index, d->
     
      ListItem{...}
      
      if(index == n){ 
         // focus on any child focus area of nth item
      }
    
   }
}

@Composable
fun ListItem(...) { ListItemLayer1{...} }

@Composable
fun ListItemLayer1(...) { ListItemLayer2{...} }

@Composable
fun ListItemLayerX(...) { 
    // 2 or 3 focusables, 
    Box(Modifier.focusable()) {...}
    Box(Modifier.focusable()) {...}

    if(...) Box(Modifier.focusable()) {...}
}
```

Comment: You can use `FocusManager`, [check this post](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/focus-in-jetpack-compose-6584252257fe)